# Fuelphp - pass default parameter to a controller in a rewrote route

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

I want to do something I thought was pretty basic using fuelphp
Basically I need to use multiple urls with only one controller, and assign each different route a default parameter (a cat id for that matter)

For instance in my Listing controller I want to use 2 different routes :

```
/bags
/accessories
```

to each of which would be assigned it's cat id

Can't seem to find any easy way to do it in fuelphp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a route like `'path/here/(:segment) => 'controller/cat/$1` which will then pass the segment captured in the route as the first parameter to a method called `action_cat` in the controller class.

This behaviour is pretty well outlined in the documentation http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/routing.html

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear in my question. I am aware of that behavior. My problem is that I don't want to use a (:segment) param. I wantto be able to route urls like 'http://example.com/we-make-wonderful-bags' and 'http://example.com/we-also-make-wonderful-leather-socks' to the same controller, assigning each of them a different cat id like 'controller/cat/1' and 'controller/cat/2'. My tests weren't ok on that. Thanks for your answer anyway mate

Comment: If you want you can also use closures/anonymous functions to return different destination uris.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the relevant link to the docs http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/routing.html#/inline_routes

Comment: yes it works this way, but I thought there would have been a much simpler and straightforward way to it. Anyway it's done, thanks

Comment: Last thing I need is to know how to retrieve the parameters I've put in the request, from inside the controller. $this->params(), \Input::get \Input::post don't get me a thing... My final route looks like that: 
'bags' => function () {
return \Request::forge('front/listing')->execute(array("catId" => "1"));        
}

Comment: Your route closure does not have to forge the request, it's better to have it return the UI where it should go. But in regards to the parameters, If you have a controller called `Welcome` and a route that ends up as `welcome/index/123` the action can have a parameter. `public function action_index($id)`. `$id` would be `123` in this case.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!